# Does "Anschrift" include e-mail?

Tags: letter

If something is required to be sent to somebody's "Anschrift", does that allow for sending an e-mail? In other words, can e-mail be used as an Anschrift?

Comment: Depends on context and convention.

Answer (score 7):

Wenn sich aus dem Kontext nicht ergibt, dass auch eine E-Mail-Adresse gemeint sein könnte, wie man das etwa bei der Bestellung eines Newsletters vermuten würde, ist in der Regel eine Anschrift für physische Post gemeint, insbesondere im Rechtsverkehr.

Allerdings gibt es gerade im [Rechtsverkehr](https://www.heise.de/newsticker/meldung/E-Mail-Adresse-im-Impressum-ist-Pflicht-1964258.html) ein Beispiel, dass explizit eine E-Mail-Anschrift verlangt wird, woraus sich schlüssig ergibt, dass eine E-Mail-Adresse ein Spezialfall von Anschrift ist.

Auch Behörden sprechen von der [E-Mail-Anschrift](https://www.berlin.de/ba-spandau/aktuelles/pressemitteilungen/2014/pressemitteilung.282735.php).

Die Antwort lautet also "Ja, aber ...", denn wenn der Kontext nicht nahelegt, dass eine E-Mail-Adresse genügt, wird man sich selten darauf berufen können, dass auch eine E-Mail-Adresse eine Anschrift sei.

Kontaktformulare im Netz oder andere Formulare klären diese Frage aber meist schon funktional (fehlende Angaben werden abgewiesen) oder gestalterisch (Aufteilung der Anschrift in Name, Straße, PLZ, Ort).

Answer (score 4):

No.

Anschrift = postal address, i.e. an address which is able to receive (physical) letters and boxes.

This is not necessarily the location of the receiver. Also a mailbox in a post office can be used as *Anschrift*.

The address of the location of a person is *»Adresse«*. This is the location where a person is registered. (In Germany, Austria and Switzerland every person needs to be registered to the authorities at an *Adresse*.) A mailbox can not be an *Adresse*.

So if you rent a mailbox at a post office, your *Adresse* and your *Anschrift* are different.

---

But maybe the receiver will accept e-mails too. Better ask the receiver.

Comment: Adresse und location waren gar nicht gefragt. Es bläht die Antwort auf, die so profunder wirkt, als sie ist. Der entscheidende Punkt, 'physical letters' ist eingeklammert, also doch in Frage gestellt. Dass man einen Kühlschrank nicht an eine E-Mailadresse liefern kann ist dem Frager bestimmt auch so klar.

Comment: [Adresse](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adresse) and [Wohnanschrift](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postanschrift) are usually synonyms, to differentiate the term [Wohnadresse](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wohnadresse) may be used. / But I *very much* agree with Hubert: if there is no explicit mention of "(e)mail", then an email address is *not* meant or required. Apart from communication that originates online, where such an address would be either already revealed or have a special form field to enter it anyway, email addresses should never be used.

Comment: I don't think that "Adresse" necessarily has to be the address of the location of a person. [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Adresse) lists "Anschrift" as meaning of "Adresse", and vice versa. See also [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adresse). By the way, the [Deutsche Post](https://www.deutschepost.de/de/b/briefumschlag-richtig-beschriften.html) uses the term "Postfachadresse".

Comment: [We already have a Q & A on the difference between *Anschrift* and *Adresse*](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/33366/difference-between-anschrift-and-adresse) -  a link to this Q & A would make the answer more helpful. Also note the common term: *E-Mail-Adresse* which would contradict you assumption that a mailbox can not be an *Adresse*.

Answer (score 1):

Absent any other information I'm going to go with yes.
If the request is for simple information or something that could commonly be sent in an email and an email address is provided no one will be upset that they don't get a physical letter.

Instructions should have been given prior on whether or not email would be acceptable in nearly all cases, though. For example many contracts require you to quit a service by regular mail (but courts lately tend to disagree that this is a requirement).

In short: it's difficult to answer without knowing specifics.

Comment: In practice I have never heard anybody saying *Bitte senden Sie es an folgende Anschrift* when he or she meant an e-mail address. Usually a person mentioning an *Anschrift* would mean a postal address. Of course, exceptions are possible, and habits may change.